# is there linear interpolation sql query?

Tags: sql

I have two tables. Table1 has data recorded at 10 sec intervals and the data in Table2 was recorded at 1 or 2 sec intervals. I want to join these two tables in a way that it will select the whole data from Table1 joined with Table2 where the recording time matches or the recording time in Table two is near to the recording time in Table1. 
For example, one row in Table1 was recorded at 21:11:20. This row should be joined with a row in Table2 recorded at 21:11:20 if it exists, otherwise, selects the nearest row, let's say a row at 21:11:19.
Thank you.

[Table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYGqt.png)

[Table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEkET.png)

Comment: 1) Which DBMS are you using? Please, tag your question with it. 2) Can you show example data? 3) How much is "near"?

Comment: It is definitely doable by creating a view, but we need to know the DBMS first ...

Comment: Without a database tag or sample data or desired results, this question is just too broad.

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
select t1.* from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on date_trunc('sec',t1.val) = t2.val;
```

Databases that allow for function indexes will do slightly better with this query than those without.

Answer (score 0):

It takes a little effort, but it is clearly doable (here: SQL-Server):

```
-- set upt a test environment with two tables:
create table tbl1  ( i1 int identity primary key,  t1 time,  v1 float);
create table tbl10 (i10 int identity primary key, t10 time, v10 float);

-- fill them with some test values:
insert into tbl1 (t1,v1) VALUES ('12:00:06',1),('12:00:07',2),('12:00:08',3),('12:00:09',3),('12:00:10',2),('12:00:11',1),('12:00:12',0);
insert into tbl10 (t10,v10) VALUES ('12:00:00',99),('12:00:10',100),('12:00:20',98),('12:00:30',110);

-- and "join" them with interpolation
WITH t10s AS (
  SELECT i10, t10, v10, DATEDIFF(second,0,t10) s10 FROM tbl10
)

SELECT t1,v1, v10a*f+v10b*(1.-f) v10int FROM (
 SELECT t1, v1, CAST(b-DATEDIFF(second,0.,t1) AS FLOAT)/(b-a) f, ta.v10 v10a, tb.v10 v10b
 FROM (
   select t1, v1,
    (SELECT max(s10) FROM t10s WHERE t10<=t1) a, 
    (SELECT min(s10) FROM t10s WHERE t10> t1) b
   FROM tbl1 
 ) tmp1
 INNER JOIN t10s ta ON ta.s10=a
 INNER JOIN t10s tb ON tb.s10=b
) tmp2

-- output:
      t1  v1  v10int
12:00:06   1    99.6
12:00:07   2    99.7
12:00:08   3    99.8
12:00:09   3    99.9
12:00:10   2   100.0
12:00:11   1    99.8
12:00:12   0    99.6
```

see the little demo here: https://rextester.com/PQDH85753

In my rudimentary script I had the situation of always having `t10` values greater or smaller than the `t1` values. To protect against "getting out of range" you could use a `COALESCE()` function with a default value that applies outside the range.